Calling eval with a variable of type string returns an error
I have a problem with the eval function in python. I have a window in tinker that returns me a string value. I pass them to eval and I get a syntax error. In the name field, enter 'abc'. Why?
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror

fieldnames = ('name', 'age', 'job', 'pay')



def makeWidgets():
    global entries
    window = Tk()
    window.title('People Shelve')
    form = Frame(window)
    form.pack()
    entries = {}
    for (ix, label) in enumerate(('key',) + fieldnames):
        lab = Label(form, text=label)
        ent = Entry(form)
        lab.grid(row=ix, column=0)
        ent.grid(row=ix, column=1)
        entries[label] = ent
    Button(window, text="Update", command=updateRecord).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(window, text="Quit", command=window.quit).pack(side=RIGHT)
    return window



def updateRecord():
    for field in fieldnames:
        text = entries[field].get()
        eval(text) # ERROR invalid syntax

window = makeWidgets()
window.mainloop()

I want to find out why I'm getting an error. I want this error explained to me.

First -- if you log the string you're about to eval, you can take all the tkinter out of the question. Part of [mre] guidelines is being minimal -- having the fewest possible factors involved. Second, why do you not expect an error if what you're evaluating is the string abc? You don't have any variable by that name. Third, using eval at all is a code smell -- which is to say, an indication that something was generally done wrong. We'd need to know why you chose to use it to speak more to what to do instead, though.

Because this is an example from the book?

If your fields are left empty, you do the following: eval(""). This results in an error because you cannot evaluate an empty string.

If a book is promoting eval use, I have questions about the wisdom of its authors. Separate from that, though -- we still need to know which string is being eval'd before we can say whether that string is something reasonably expected to be valid syntax. And once you log the string so you can tell us what it is, you can take all the tkinter out of the question and just ask why eval('that string') fails, replacing 'that string' with the actual value.

My error is SyntaxError: invalid syntax NOT NameError: name 'abc' is not defined

nod. We don't know that it is 'abc' being eval'd, because you aren't logging the string. Fix that first; then you'll have enough information to ask a better question.

Byt my variable text have value 'abc' when i type 'abc' in name field

Try: print(text) then print(eval(text)).  If you aren't getting a NameError then abc must be defined somewhere that you haven't shown us.  If abc = 1 is added to your code, then eval('abc') will return 1 for example, but not saved, so essentially nothing happens.  eval("") gives a syntax error, which you would get on the next loop of for field in fieldnames: because it would read the blank entry for age.

@Anina, do you see my comment above? Are your other fields empty?

You're iterating over multiple fields. You may have typed abc in one field, but we don't know that that's the first one in iteration order; and since you aren't logging, you don't know either.

when i print(text) i get 'abc'. Can you run this code on your machine and try it?

(Also, print(repr(text)), not print(text) -- lots of room for hidden characters &c to make something invalid as code if you don't get an ASCII representation)

I have to put a value in each field otherwise I will have eval(""). Sorry. Thank you very much. Problem solve.

@CharlesDuffy I think you don't quite understand how Entry works in Tkinter. When you enter 'abc' in the field, the value returned is "'abc'", so it would be eval("'abc'"), which would be absolutely fine and return 'abc'.

@DanyaK OH! OP is literally typing 'abc' (with quotes) not abc.  In any event, using eval is just wrong here and OP isn't using the return value anyway.  updateRecord does nothing.

@DanyaK, '' being printed would have made the whole question unnecessary, because it would have made the problem obvious. Without the quotes you just have a blank line, which is a lot less clear.

The problem is that if some of your fields are empty, entries[field].get() will return an empty string "". So you will try to evaluate an empty string (eval('')), which you can't do. This results in the error you see. You can fix this in different ways, for example, check if the text is not empty string, like this:
text = entries[field].get()
if text != '':
    eval(text)

Or you can add try except block, like this:
text = entries[field].get()
try:
    eval(text)
except SyntaxError:
    print("no values in a field")
except NameError:
    print("text must be entered as 'some text'")

